# MongoDB compare field value using IF statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

So in my project I want to take a Field in my collection and compare it with an if statement in TypeScript.

My code:

```
const memberID = 'john';

const profile = await userSchema.findOne({userID: memberID});

//My userSchema also contains a field called level which is type number

const intLvl = parseInt(profile?.level?);

if(intLvl >= 10){
  //do stuff
}
```

So basically I want to check if field "level" is greater than or equal to 10 and if it is carry on with the if statement?